# Little help needed with C Code

Tags: c

Hello I am working on a line follower robot with a single IR sensor .

I have been provided the simulation client + hardware . I am trying simulation part now in which I have to move robot along valid path until I found a token in the maze. Then stop
and give out the coordinates x, y like this: "token found on x , y". The coordinates
given by the server application based on a global coordinate system (e.g. east, west...)
your robot has an local coordinate system (e.g. to the left, to the right, forward...).
Choose an orientation of the robot at start and show on screen, the actual coordinates
too. Before every movement send to the server application give out on the screen the
necessary correction of the robots orientation ("to the left", "forward","to the right",
"turn around") and then the coordinates send to the server.
Example:
Welcome to Sim
Robot is on intersection: 3 , 5
with orientation to: south
robot move: to the left
robot go to: 4 , 5
...
token found on: 2 , 1

There are two ways to simulate the program either locally or on remote server , on local machine I can see the maze but on remote server is always gives me the unknown maze.

I have two C file

**roboproxy.c**

```
    #include <stdarg.h>
#include "../h/RobotProxy.h"

/// initialized with ROBOT_FAIL
int currentIntersection = ROBOT_FAIL;

#if !defined(vasprintf)
static int vasprintf(char **s, const char *format, va_list ap) {
    /* Guess we need no more than 100 bytes. */
    int n, size = 100;
    va_list save_ap;

    if ((*s = (char*) malloc(size)) == NULL)
        return -1;
    while (1) {
        /* work on a copy of the va_list because of a bug
         in the vsnprintf implementation in x86_64 libc
         */
#ifdef __va_copy
        __va_copy(save_ap, ap);
#else
        save_ap = ap;
#endif
        /* Try to print in the allocated space. */
#ifdef _vsnprintf
        n = _vsnprintf(*s, size, format, save_ap);
#else
        n = vsnprintf(*s, size, format, save_ap);
#endif
        va_end(save_ap);
        /* If that worked, return the string. */
        if (n > -1 && n < size) {
            return n;
        }
        /* Else try again with more space. */
        if (n > -1) { /* glibc 2.1 */
            size = n + 1; /* precisely what is needed */
        } else { /* glibc 2.0 */
            size *= 2; /* twice the old size */
        }
        if ((*s = (char*) realloc(*s, size)) == NULL) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
#endif

#if !defined(asprintf)
static int asprintf(char **s, const char *format, ...) {
    va_list vals;
    int result;

    va_start(vals, format);
    result = vasprintf(s, format, vals);
    va_end(vals);
    return result;
}
#endif

/// Set the robot to the specified position
/// @ returns ROBOT_SUCCESS, ROBOT_FAIL or ROBOT_TOKENFOUND
int Robot_Move(int x, int y) {
    char* buffer;
    asprintf(&buffer, "{\"x\":%d,\"y\":%d}", x, y);
    char* query = url_encode(buffer);
    free(buffer);
    char* response = sendAndRecieve(concat(URL, query));

    if (response == NULL) {
        puts("Connection to server failed!");
        return ROBOT_FAIL;
    }

    if (contains(response, "\"code\":1")) {
        puts("Connection declined!");
        return ROBOT_FAIL;
    }

    if (contains(response, "\"code\":2")) {
        puts("Connection blocked!");
        return ROBOT_FAIL;
    }

    if (contains(response, "\"code\":3")) {
        printf("Invalid position! (x=%d, y=%d)\n", x, y);
        return ROBOT_FAIL;
    }

    int foundIntersection = 0;
    bool token = false;

    if (contains(response, "\"north\":true"))
        foundIntersection |= D_N;
    if (contains(response, "\"east\":true"))
        foundIntersection |= D_E;
    if (contains(response, "\"south\":true"))
        foundIntersection |= D_S;
    if (contains(response, "\"west\":true"))
        foundIntersection |= D_W;

    if (contains(response, "\"token\":true"))
        token = true;

    free(query);

    currentIntersection = foundIntersection;
    if (token)
        return ROBOT_TOKENFOUND;

    return ROBOT_SUCCESS;
}

/// Get the intersections of the current node that the robot is at
/// @ returns always the intersection at position x=0,y=0 if Robot_Move was not called first
int Robot_GetIntersections() {
    if (currentIntersection == ROBOT_FAIL)
        Robot_Move(0, 0);
    return currentIntersection;
}
```

Roboclientsim.C

```
    #include "../h/Configuration.h"

int main(void) {

    printf("Token: %d\n", Robot_Move(1, 0));
    printf("Intersection: %d\n", Robot_GetIntersections());

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

as I run the program in console It gives me that Token is 1 and then after finding any token it will become 2.

so in roboclientsim.c I added 
"

```
 If (Robot_Move()==2) //as Robot_move is returning the %d value for Token
printf("another token found ");
```

"

But my compiler is giving problem that few arguemnts for the robot_move,

Can anyone help me with this how to do it?

Comment: `Robot_Move` is a function that takes two arguments, you cannot call it without any argument.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! "Wall of code" questions are not a good fit for the Q&A format of the site. You need to isolate the problem to something more specific than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Robot_Move` takes 2 arguments:

```
int Robot_Move(int x, int y);
```

And you call it without any argument.

```
If (Robot_Move()==2)
```

That's the error. I suspect that what you wanted to do was:

```
int main(void) {
    int token = Robot_Move(1, 0);
    printf("Token: %d\n", token);
    printf("Intersection: %d\n", Robot_GetIntersections());

    if (token == 2) 
       printf("another token found ");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

or maybe:

```
int main(void) {
    int token = Robot_Move(1, 0);

    if (token == 2) {
       printf("Token: %d\n", token);
       printf("Intersection: %d\n", Robot_GetIntersections());
    } else {
       printf("another token found ");
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The thing is that these two files are in same project and toke is already defined in the robotproxy.c file as bool.

since the robot_move is returning a single %d value and I want that value , DO I need to put this condition on every intersction that if  robot move ( x , y) ==2 then printf token found 
or is there any better way to do that ?

I tried with extern variable command but it's not working with that

Comment: You absolutely need to understand the concept of local and global variables. There are plenty of good explanations on the web. Please read a tutorial about the basics of the C language. Understand that the `token` variable defined in `Robot_Move` is only accessible inside that function. Even if they share the same name, they are not the same! Don't use a global variable to do a workaround. Robot_Move returns whether it went well, do your if on it. When you write Robot_Move, you ask your robot to move.

Answer (score 0):

Check the prototype of the method
`int Robot_Move(int x, int y)`
You need to provide 2 parameters when calling it.